# Spring ROO sorting

Tags: spring, sorting

I have a set of Entities generated using Spring ROO. After several commands, basically using web mvc, I have a set of links to get the contents from a database. I need to order the contents according to title, instead of the order in the table. How can I do it? Is there any Spring ROO commando or annotation to order the items.

For more information, I am using Spring Roo 1.2.1, and the finder I got is the following.

```
 public static List<Deporte> Deporte.findAllDeportes() {
    return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Deporte o", Deporte.class).getResultList();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo uses JPA for the persistence. Search for JPA tutorials and documentation to find what you're looking for.

JPQL uses the `order by` clause to order results returned by a query. This `order by` is very similar to the SQL `order by` clause:

```
SELECT o FROM Deporte o order by o.title
```

Comment: The point is that I have to add the order by in the generated class, and that's a problem because roo regenerate it after every single change in the entity class. This is why that solution is not right. I need to add something in the entity.

Comment: JPA doesn't support order by clauses in entities. Every request chooses how its results are sorted.

Comment: And what happens with Roo. Can I add any annotation to stablish the default order? Can I change the jsp, the <table:table to order in a different way?